# Akka-Http Websockets: How to Send consumers the same stream of data

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a WebSocket that clients can connect to I also have a stream of data using akka-streams. How can I make it that all clients get the same data. At the moment they seem to be racing for the data.

Thanks

Comment: Try to implement or use a pub/sub broker channels system like Redis... and remember you can handle websocket with just a Flow or with a Flow and a Sink. The akka stream of data could finish with a sink that publish data to a channel.

Comment: @salc2 I think what I need is an Event stream with will allow a peer to many communication solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way you could do is is to have an actor that extends ActorPublisher and have it subscribe
to some message.

```
class MyPublisher extends ActorPublisher[MyData]{

  override def preStart = {
    context.system.eventStream.subscribe(self, classOf[MyData])
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case msg: MyData ⇒
      if (isActive && totalDemand > 0) {
        // Pushes the message onto the stream
        onNext(msg)
      }
  }
}

object MyPublisher {
  def props(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Props = Props(new MyPublisher())
}

case class MyData(data:String)
```

You can then use that actor as the source for the stream:

```
val dataSource = Source.actorPublisher[MyData](MyPublisher.props(someExcutionContext))
```

You can then create a flow from that datasource and apply a transform to convert the data into a websocket message

```
val myFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, dataSource map {d => TextMessage.Strict(d.data)})
```

Then you can use that flow in your route handling.

```
path("readings") {
  handleWebsocketMessages(myFlow)
}
```

From the processing of the original stream, you can then publish the data to the event stream and any instance of that actor will pick it up and put in onto the stream that their websocket is being served from.

```
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("foo")

  val otherSource = Source.fromIterator(()  => List(MyData("a"), MyData("b")).iterator)

  otherSource.runForeach { msg ⇒ actorSystem.eventStream.publish(MyData("data"))}
```

Each socket will then have its own instance of the actor to provide it with data all coming from a single source.

Comment: Thanks Al. This type of solution I tried to elude to above in the comments. This seems to be a very nice solution to the problem. I am currently trying to implement this. Thanks for the example.